# Which adapter is best on last Macbook Pro 2016 for Thunderbolt 2 dual monitors?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, dual-screen

My typical setup is to plugin in my MBP with lid closed into dual monitors. I typically bring back and forth to work in backpack, where I also have dual monitors. All of my monitors go from DVI port into a Thunderbolt 2 like so:

[image: Old MBP Ports]

Now I just got the new Macbook Pro delivered and the lack of ports is really frustrating. Looks like this:

[image: Late 2016 MBP Ports]

The ports on my old MBP is really nicely set. All are on one side and work nicely with my desk setup so that the wires all run behind my desk. On my new MBP each side only has 2 ports (except for the headphone jack). I am not able to find a way to get both displays into one USB-C where I can use the other for my USB hub for example.

My question is, is there any sort of adapters that I can use to get to a similiar setup? All I've been able to find is the Thunderbolt 2 -> 3 converter adapters, but since there is only 2 ports on each side, I'd still have to pull in more stuff into the other side of the MBP (USB, power, headphones).

Feels like Apple went all in for the pretty minimalistic approach in expense of convienence.

Is there no USB-C hubs that support dual monitors?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with for example a Thunderbolt 3 dock (or Thunderbolt 2 dock if you have an older one). Models from Belkin, OWC, etc. allow you to plugin the two monitors, your USB device, charger and audio into the dock and only have a single cable going into the new MacBook Pro.

Comment: How about statement that dual monitor setup has limitations in macos whether Dual Screen setup in real is Dual Mirror? Bootcamp works fine by the way.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Which statement are you talking about? What kind of limitations are you talking about?

Comment: Check every tb2 dock on market. They have statements about macos/display http://www.belkin.com/au/p/P-F4U085/ (Note about dual displays: At least one display has to be Thunderbolt or Thunderbolt 2 technology-ready.) http://caldigit.com/usb-3-1-usb-c-dock/ (For Mac customers looking to use dual monitors with an extended desktop this is not currently possible, as MST (Multi Stream Transport), is not supported within the Mac OS.
) https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/Dock/OWC/Thunderbolt2-Dock/ (*Dual monitor support requires the use of at least one Thunderbolt display.)

Comment: While same docks work perfect with tb monitor with same macbook while running windows.

Comment: @Noma4i I was talking about Thunderbolt 3 docks, not TB2!

Answer (score 1):

So far there are no USB-C docks that provide the "correct" amount of power for the MacBook Pro's, so far that I've seen. The Kensington SD4600P USB-C Docking Station provides just under the required power for a 13" MBPR and not even close to what the 15" needs.

Depending on what you need, you could use the Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter. That includes pass through power capabilities. That adapter would give you one monitor, and power, and USB for ethernet if you wanted. Then add one more USB-C to HDMI adapter and you're done. Two plugs and you've covered power, dual monitor and whatever USB needs you have.